# How can I get user input from command line with this program?

Tags: ruby

Im using Ruby for this program which basically does calculation of how many fives and threes you need to get the amount input. Now I am dealing with a problem I can get it to work when i have to input from the cmd like for example `ruby filename.rb 123`

```
begin

    x = Integer(gets.chomp)  
    rescue
        puts "Please input an integer"
        retry
    end
    y = 5
    atlikums = x % y
    if x % 10 == 1     
        puts   " #{(x / 5) - 1} five cent, 2 three cent "

    elsif x > 100 && x % 10 == 5 
        puts " #{x / 5} five cent " 

    elsif x < 8  
        puts "Minimal amount is 8 cents"

    elsif x==9
        puts "#{x/3} three cents"

    elsif atlikums == 0 
        puts " #{x / 5} five cents"  

    elsif atlikums == 1 
        puts " #{(x / 5) - 1} five cents, 2 three cent"

    elsif atlikums == 2
        puts " #{(x / 5) - 2} five cents, 4 three cent " 

    elsif atlikums == 3
        puts " #{x/ 5} five cents, 1 three cent" 

    elsif atlikums == 4
        puts " #{x/ 5} five cents, 3 three cent" 

    end
```

I already tried `x = ARGV` but idk that doesnt work

Comment: See [documentation for ARGF](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ARGF.html).

Comment: "idk that doesnt work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: Ugh. Stylistically, long chains of `if`/`else if` are undesirable. `case` statements can help, but that needs to be broken down. "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability." — John Woods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ARGV` is an array. You have to get its first element.

```rb
print ARGV  # An array
x = ARGV[0]
print x
```

With `ruby filename.rb 123`, `ARGV` is `["123"]` and `x` is `"123"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use command line arguments you usually first check if there are enough arguments passed (by checking `ARGV.length`), then access the arguments in `ARGV` array, assigning them to some descriptively named variables, and finally do some work using those variables.

For example there you have program, that adds two numbers (`add.rb`):

```
# Check if there are at least two command line arguments passed to the program
if ARGV.length < 2
  puts "Two arguments are required."
  puts "USAGE: ruby #{File.basename(__FILE__)} FIRST_NUMBER SECOND_NUMBER"
  exit
end
# Assign command line arguments to descriptively named variables
firstNum  = ARGV[0].to_i
secondNum = ARGV[1].to_i

# Perform some work
sum = firstNum + secondNum
puts "#{firstNum} + #{secondNum} = #{sum}"
```

You can run it like:

```
$ ruby add.rb 2 5
2 + 5 = 7
```

You surly notice that you can pass non-integers to this program, and it will fail. To fix this you can add some validation logic like:

```
if ARGV[0] =~ /^[0-9]+$/
  puts "First argument should be an integer"
  exit
end
```

This might be a solution, but most likely you would be reimplementing something that already has been implemented (e.g. checking if the string is an integer), you risk that your validation might not work with some edge cases, and you make your program over-complex. In those cases, when your command line argument processing logic becomes a little to much then you really want to deal with, you should use either [`OptionParser`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) from standard ruby library, or some non-standard [command line option parsing library](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers).